# Why do I get Can't find variable: GlobalStore in React Native ios Facebook login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using the following module in my React Native app in order to login users with Facebook. https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

I logged the following issue. 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/58

I have the following in my view and I get the GlobalStore can't find error.

```
var FBSDKLogin = require('react-native-fbsdklogin');

//init facebook login
  fbTouchHandler(event) {
    FBSDKLoginManager.setLoginBehavior(GlobalStore.getItem('behavior', 'native'));
    FBSDKLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([], (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        alert('Error logging in.');
      } else {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('Login cancelled.');
        } else {
          alert('Logged in.');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```